# How to make Django-CMS and Open Edx use same authentication for users?

Tags: python, django, django-cms, openedx

We are looking to develop a Django project in which we need to integrate three different Django packages namely a CMS (Django-CMS or Wagtail), a LMS (Open edX) and a support/ticketing system.

Since Django-CMS, Open Edx have their own user authentication, but we want them to share a common authentication (username, password, user profiles), so that a user logged into one section of website is able to move to other sections smoothly.

How to make these different packages share same authentication?
Is there any guidelines or procedure to integrate these different Django Packages?

(Google search about such integration of packages doesnot have any clear documentation, so I decided to ask this on stackoverflow)